# Show that $\Pr(|X_1|\ge a_{kn})\ge\frac1k\Pr(|X_1|\ge a_k)$

Tags: probability-theory

> If $a_n$ is positive for all $n$ and $\frac{a_n}{n}\uparrow$(increasing) is then $\Pr(|X_1|\ge a_{kn})\ge\frac1k\Pr(|X_1|\ge a_n)$, if not why is at least $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\Pr(|X_1|\ge a_{kn})\ge\frac1k\sum\limits_{m=k}^\infty\Pr(|X_1|\ge a_m)$

where $X_1$ is a some random variable with $\mathbb E|X_1|=\infty$ (does it play a role ?)

It is from https://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf#page=79, ($4^{th}$ line under Theorem 2.5.9 the $2^{nd}$ inequality)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

From the earlier line, we see that $\frac{a_n}{n} \uparrow \implies a_{kn}>ka_n$

Lets start at $n=1$:

$$a_k>ka_1$$

Therefore,

$$a_2>a_1 \implies ka_1<a_k<\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i$$

Then,

$$Pr(|X_1|\ge ka_1)\geq Pr(|X_1|\ge a_k) \geq Pr\left(|X_1|\ge \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i\right)$$

But,

$$Pr\left(|X_1|\ge \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}Pr\left(|X_1|\ge a_i\right)\leq kPr\left(|X_1|\ge a_1\right)$$

Comment: but in the last line you have to have some inequality in the other direction, i.e. LHS $\ge$ RHS, whatever I think I got the soluton: $\Pr(|X|\ge a_k)\ge\frac1k\sum\limits_{m=k}^{2k-1}\Pr(|X|\ge a_m),\quad$ and

$\Pr(|X|\ge a_{2k})\ge\frac1k\sum\limits_{m=2k}^{3k-1}\Pr(|X|\ge a_m)\dots$

Comment: @ketum great, glad you were able to make progress.